# How to use X window to create a GUI for Linux OS interface?

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Can you provide me a surface level knowledge about this.

How can I use linux's latest kernel and X windows GUI to create my own Embedded OS interface?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn to make your own distribution, look at linux from scratch.  A pre-existing embedded distribution may be more what you are looking for. Some are uclinux-dist, openembedded, poky, ltib, buildroot.

When you say "small" what do you mean by small?  Small means reduced functionality.

1. The smallest is writing your own code that writes to the frame buffer.  Your GUI may look like space invaders.
2. Bigger would be to use a direct to framebuffer toolkit like Nano-X
3. Bigger again is DirectFB.
4. Bigger again is a high level toolkit
   (GTK or Qt) on top of DirectFB
5. And the biggest is X with a window
   manager and high level toolkit.

Having "learned" already, I would use whatever comes with the platform you are developing on.

End Dump.

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion, code HTML and use a browser.  All of the heavy lifting will be done for you.  More to the point, most embedded OSen do not live on systems with keyboards, video, and mice.  Exporting everything to a remote web client though a web server is the standard way of doing things.

Second suggestion, use a high level toolkit, like Qt, KDE, or Gnome.  Coding in low level X is painful.

Comment: Or use OpenGL for drawing, not low level X window nor painful. :)

Comment: I just wanted to learn to create very small OS like muLinux that could be installed in very limited space. Side by side I also wanted to learn how system works.

Comment: @DizitalTech: I recommend a webserver based management system then, not X11.   Your task is challenging enough without throwing graphical programming into the mix.  Oh, and setting up gentoo from scratch is a good way to understand some of the basics in your task.